# Do the concepts of typographic scale and vertical rhythm apply equally to print media and web apps?

Tags: gui-design, web-app, typography

I have been learning about these two fundamental concepts and I see how beneficial they are for print media (including 'digital print' like blogs and webzines.) do these concepts apply equally to dynamic or data-driven web applications, and should designers strive to regularly apply them in such projects as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just because the medium changes doesn't mean visual balance no longer applies. Because web apps are in a browser and browser sizes vary depending on the user, it is a bit different when comparing it to print media, where the designer knows explicitly the dimensions of the final product.

Design is not an exact science, but setting appropriate css rules with a proper hierarchy of font weight, sizes, and margins will help with scale and vertical rhythm - so yes, they are equally important, but they are different in application because web apps can have much more content.

Comment: "where the designer knows explicitly the dimensions of the final product." <-- But he also needs to be aware of how this product will be perceived. An ingredients table on a chocolate bar package a handsize away from you or a city ad of several m² 150 m away from you